# Cross-Site-Collection SharePoint "XSL Link" Property

Tags: sharepoint, list, xslt

Must the **XSL Link** property in a SharePoint 2010 List View web part reference a document in the same site collection? This appears to be the case, but I don't find the restriction documented one way or the other. My interest is in providing Site Collection administrators centrally-located XSLs for "nice" list views, without installing (and maintaining) 100 copies of the same stylesheet across the application.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, you could do something like this in the originating site collection's xsl file...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="REFERENCE TO THE MASTER SITE COLLECTION'S XSL FILE" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-imports />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried it and kept getting 401 Unauthorized, but it may work for you.

Last resort is, build a wsp file and deploy it to the _layouts directory in the hive.  That's how MS does it.